# In C how can I find in a directory all the file names and store them in a array of strings of characters?

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

I create a code in C to find all file names in a directory, this code is recursive so if it finds other directories within this will review the others directories. The search in the directory and the search of files works well,, because i printed on screen what the program read and i realized that find all filenames and does not repeat any filename. The problem i have is that i saves into an array of strings of characters the file name found, and when you find all the files i will have in the main the arrangement of strings with all the file names, but when i printed on screen that arrangement there is not all the files in it, but a few repeated files names. The ultimate goal of this program is not print all file names in screen, the purpose is to save in the arrangement all the file names .I can not see the error, if someone can tell me something that I'm doing wrong I'll be grateful.

```
 void findfiles(char *root,char *p[],int *tam){
    DIR * dir;
    struct dirent *entrada;
    struct stat stt;
    dir = opendir(root);
    char *aux;
    char nombre[BUFFER_TAM];
    char buf[30];
    if (dir == NULL) {
            printf("hola4\n");
            return;
     }
 while ((entrada = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(entrada->d_name,".")==0 || strcmp(entrada->d_name,"..")==0);
            else {
                if (entrada->d_type == DT_DIR){
                    strcpy(nombre,root);
                    strcat(nombre,"/");
                    strcat(nombre,entrada->d_name);
                    findfiles(nombre,p,tam);
                }
                else {
                    strcpy(nombre,root);
                    strcat(nombre,"/");
                    strcat(nombre,entrada->d_name);
                    p[*tam]=malloc(strlen(nombre)+1);
                    p[*tam]=nombre;
                    *tam = *tam +1;
                }
            }
        }
```

}

```c
void main(){
    char *archivos[BUFFER_TAM];
    char root[BUFFER_TAM]="/home/jesusmolina/Documentos";
    int i=0,tam=0;
    findfiles(root,archivos,&tam);
    for (i;i<tam;i++)
       printf("%s\n",archivos[i]);
}
```

Comment: For starters, get rid of the `';'` following your `if ..."..")==0);` (you should be receiving compiler warnings/errors regarding unmatched `else`)

Comment: Here is a tip for you: Your question is a good question, but the title does not contain the actual question you have, but another one that you have already answered and which looks very old to most people. You will get more help with a better worded title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                p[*tam]=malloc(strlen(nombre)+1);
                p[*tam]=nombre;
```

You allocate a chunk of memory, then immediately lose the pointer to that memory and leak it. You probably wanted:

```
                p[*tam]=malloc(strlen(nombre)+1);
                strcpy(p[*tam], nombre);
```